# Replace Value when all content is digit python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Below is a **sample** of my df

```
id  name 
01  1
02  23 2    
03  234     
04  23423   
05  24 H AUTOSERVICE    
06  25 SUNGLASS
```

The aim is to 'clean' the DF by replacing digits with NaN only if the whole value contains digits.

The expected output would look like this

```
id  name 
01  NaN
02  24 H AUTOSERVICE    
03  25 SUNGLASS
```

I was thinking about something like this. Besides, it would remove all digits even 24 H

```
 df['name'] = df['name'].replace(r'[0-9]', '')
```

Thanks for anyone helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with negative selection `[]` of numbers and also whitespace `\s`  and [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['name'] = df['name'].where(df['name'].str.contains('[^0-9\s]'))
print (df)
   id              name
0   1               NaN
1   2               NaN
2   3               NaN
3   4               NaN
4   5  24 H AUTOSERVICE
5   6       25 SUNGLASS
```

For remove consecutive `NaN`s:

```
m = df['name'].isna()
df = df[m.ne(m.shift()) | ~m]
print (df)
   id              name
0  01               NaN
4  05  24 H AUTOSERVICE
5  06       25 SUNGLASS
```

Comment: Using the Mask and isnumeric doesnt solve this issue when the value is : 123 456?